Regular expression : match a sequence of char and a repeating group
I am trying to setup a regular expression to validate variables names.
The rules are relatively simple, but I am no reg-ex jedi :)
it must start with a lettre or a underscore
[a-zA-Z_]

it can be followed by any repetition of letters or number, or dash "-" underscore "_" OR dot "."
[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]*

so far so good
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]*

BUT it may also include a number of repetition of this pattern \[\w+\]
this pattern, it like any of the other chars, it can appear any number of times, except at the first letter.
so I tried a few options such as
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]*(\[\w+\])*

or
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.(\[\w+\])]*

I never got around to find the right syntax.
The idea is quite simple, it's a pattern, and it can located like any of the chars in the second sequence, one or more time, in any order
If this is not clear, see examples below
### valid examples
valid_var_name[a]
valid3_va[x].[y].name
valid_myVar[w].x
valide_myVar[a1].sub[b].SUB1_2[c].sub[d1].sub[d1].sub[d1].sub[d1].sub[d1].sub[d1].isValid

### invalid examples
2invalid     // start with a number
.invalid     // start with a dot
invalid[]    // nothing between bracket
invalid].name      // char ] alone is invalid
invalid[.]name     // [.] dot is not a word
invalid[].name[1]  // [] without a word not valid  


You have a typo here: (\[\w+\[) should be (\[\w+\])

Should var1[var2.var3] be allowed? or var1[var2[var3]]?

What language are you attempting to run the regex in? different engines have different short hands and escape sequences.

I corrected the typo, and Java is the target.

@Barmar no, just simple words within square brackets, thanks :)

Why would you put (\[\w+\]) inside the [...] character set? That makes no sense.

@Barmar : simply because I don`t know how to express what I am looking for in a regex :)

regex is hard to read, so any abbreviation helps: Dots don't need escaping in character classes, nor do dashes if first or last and [a-zA-Z_0-9] can be coded as \w, so for example [a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.] can be coded as just [\w.-]

You could try ^[a-zA-Z_](\.?(\w|\[\w+\]))*$

Try ^(?:[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:\[\w+])*|\[\w+])(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?:\[\w+])*|\[\w+]))*$, too. (demo)

@WiktorStribiżew your regex would match "[test]" - see your own demo

@DuesserBaest Yes, since [word] is expected to match.

@WiktorStribiżew is it? "it must start with a lettre or a underscore"

See [y] in the examples that should match. So, we need to match these anyway. Restricting the first part is easy anyway - https://regex101.com/r/dzjvmm/4

^[a-zA-Z_]([\w\-.]|\[\w+\])*$

This starts with an alphabetic or underscore, then allows any sequence of either alphanumerics, -, ., or [name]
The anchors are needed so it won't match a variable in the middle of a string, like variable in 2variable.
DEMO

Maybe foo..bar and foo. should be ruled out, too
